Laser interference fringes fading in and out of view
I'm working in a lab this summer doing quantum optics, and my team is working on a Mach-Zehnder interferometer setup. We got it well aligned and interference fringes appeared as expected. However, soon after building it, the fringes began to fade in and out of view without us changing anything about the setup, and we can't figure out why.
This is how it looks: there is a circular beam showing up on a screen with dark interference lines going across it. The interference lines fade to the point where the beam looks uniform as if there is no interference and then they'll come back into view. This happens quite often (about 10 times per minute) and it's random rather than periodic. As the fringes fade, they mostly don't move or change in size. Typically, the only thing that changes is their brightness, although occasionally the bright and dark fringes change places.
The only thing we know of that changes randomly over time is the laser intensity. It fluctuates a slight bit, but we found no correlation between the laser intensity and the visibility of the interference fringes.
What could be the cause of this issue, and how should we fix this?

Is the experiment on an optical table?

If not vibrations could be messing with the interference.

It is on an optical table, but we tried bumping the table and it had no effect on the fringes

Have you tried using another laser?

Also you might want to try just measuring the laser's intensity over an extended period to see if there is a problem with the laser.

https://www.toptica.com/fileadmin/Editors_English/12_literature/01_quantum_technologies/toptica_12_orders_of_coherence_control.pdf

Sounds like a laser with unstable frequency/modes. The instability might be caused by the connection to the interferometer. It may not present if you shine the beam on a dark surface like that of an intensity meter. The laser seems OK when you are measuring its intensity and it croaks when the reflection from your interferometer messes up its optical gain. You need to isolate the interferometer from the laser. A beam splitter or a simple gray filter might suffice.

You should check with the manufacturer of the laser. It is common for coherence of fringes to vary as the laser warms up.  It is possible there is some feedback into the laser, but then the oscillations would usually be on a shorter time scale. I assume you are running the laser through a pinhole in order to clean up the beam and insure a single zeroth order mode.

Another thing you can do is to make the path difference closer to true 0. It seems that the laser has frequency problems so your coherence length is changing. As you probably have a lot of fringes, the separation between the two arms probably is close to the roll-off of your laser frequency stability. If you can align it better to have the arms much closer in length, the fringes will fade much less.

We tried a lot of different things, but we couldn't find a solution. Instead, we wrote a program that helps us filter out the bad data. Thanks for your help!
